# Application slows down over time - Java + Python

Tags: java, python, tomcat, garbage-collection, fedora-commons

This is a difficult one to explain, and not hopeful for a single, simple answer, but thought it's worth a shot.  Interested in what might slow down a long Python job that interacts with a Java application.

We have an instance of Tomcat running a fairly complex and robust webapp called [Fedora Commons](http://fedorarepository.org/about) (not to be confused with Fedora the OS), software for storing digital objects.  Additionally, we have a python middleware that performs long background jobs with [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).  One particular job is ingesting a 400+ page book, where each page of the book has a large TIFF file, then some smaller PDF, XML, and metadata files.  Over the course of 10-15 minutes, derivatives are created from these files and they are added to a single object in Fedora.

Our problem: over the course of ingesting one book, adding files to the digital object in the Java app Fedora Commons slows down very consistently and predictably, but I can't figure out how or why.

I thought a graph of the ingest speeds might help, perhaps it belies a common memory management pattern that those more experienced with Java might recognize:

[image]

The top-left graph is timing large TIFFs, being converted to JP2, then ingested into Fedora Commons.   The bottom-left is very small XML files, with no derivative being made, ingested as well.  As you can see, the slope of their curve slowing down is almost identical.  On the right, are those two processes graphed together.

I've been all over the internet trying to learn about garbage collection in Java (GC), trying different configurations, but not having much effect on the slowdown.  If it helps, here are some memory configurations we're passing to Tomcat (where the tail-end I believe are mostly diagnostic):

`JAVA_OPTS='-server -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:SurvivorRatio=10 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/var/log/tomcat7/ggc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC'`

We're working with `12GB` of RAM on this VM.

I realize the number of factors that might result in this behavior are, excuse the pun, off the charts.  But we've worked with Fedora Commons and our Python middleware for quite some time, and been mostly successful.  This slow down you could set your watch too just feels suspiciously Java / garbage collection related, though I could be very wrong about that too.

Any help or advice for digging in more is appreciated!

Comment: is the python part running on the jvm via jython? or is it a separate process? if it's the latter you first should identify which part of your whole machinery slows down, i.e. whether it's the java or the python part.

Comment: Try adding Psi-Probe to your Fedora Commons Tomcat instance. By looking only at the job complete times you can't tell what component of your Fedora Commons install is causing the slowdown. The problem could be Fedora, gSearch, Solr, or Djatoka. By adding Psi-Probe you will be able to check performance at the servlet level and better pinpoint the problem.

https://psi-probe.github.io/psi-probe/

Comment: This is great, thanks @RickSarvas!  I recognize many of those components as going hand-in-hand with Islandora, which we are not using.  But Psi-Probe sounds general enough to Tomcat that it might be very useful.  Appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for the suggestions around GC and Tomcat analysis.  Turns out, the slowdown was entirely due to ways that Fedora Commons builds digital objects.  I was able to isolate this by creating an extremely simple digital object, iteratively adding near zero-size datastreams and watching the progress.  You can see this in the graph below:

[image: graph of adding datastreams]

The curve of the slowdown as almost identical, which suggested it was not our particular ingest method or file sizes.  Furthermore, prompted me to dig back into [old forum posts about Fedora Commons](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/fedora-community/datastream$20limit/fedora-community/BMASQyMZtio/5KSTeRfHUpoJ) which confirm that single objects are not meant to contain a large number of datastreams.

It is perhaps interesting how this knowledge was obfuscated behind intellectual organization of digital objects, and not specifically the performance hits you take with Fedora, but that's probably fodder for another forum.

Thanks again to all for the suggestions - if nothing else, normal usage of Fedora is finer tuned and humming along better than before.

Answer (score 0):

You say you suspect GC as the problem, but you show no GC metrics.  Put your program through a profiler and see why the GC is overloaded.  It is hard to solve a problem without identifying the cause.

Once you have the found where the problem lies, likely you will need to change the code instead of just tweaking GC settings.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion - I'll see what I can do as far as profiling.  I've watched the GCC logs, and see a LOT of "invocations" which I've thought might mean "minor" GC, but not many major ones.  But agreed, profiling results would help (those GC Tomcat settings were from others profiling and tuning their Fedora Commons ingest process).

Comment: Unfortunately  a high number of GC invocations is pretty standard for Java code, especially in applications that were not optimized for speed but for resource usage.

Answer (score -1):

Well, instead of looking into obscure GC settings, you might want to start managing memory explicitly, so the GC doesn't affect your execution that much.

Comment: When you say "managing memory explicitly", do you mean in the Java code?  Not equipped to edit / update the Fedora Commons code, though we do have access to the Python code.

Comment: Yes, i was talking about Java, but you can take a look at your Python allocations as well. Like puhlen said, you should also look at a few other metrics, cpu load, memory usage etc. Without these it's hard to give recommendations.